# regarding the code performing region boundary based RAGs using skimage

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, scikit-learn, scikit-image

Regarding the [Region Boundary based RAGs](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/segmentation/plot_rag_boundary.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-segmentation-plot-rag-boundary-py), I am not clear about the code on defining edges_rgb, if I perform the RAG analysis over a gray image, why I need to transfer the edges into rgb color?

```
edges_rgb = color.gray2rgb(edges)
g = graph.rag_boundary(labels, edges)
lc = graph.show_rag(labels, g, edges_rgb, img_cmap=None, edge_cmap='viridis',
                    edge_width=1.2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out you don't. This code does the same thing:

```py
g = graph.rag_boundary(labels, edges)
lc = graph.show_rag(labels, g, edges, img_cmap='gray', edge_cmap='viridis',
                    edge_width=1.2)
```

I guess the original author preferred using `gray2rgb` and no colormapping. But it's a matter of preference, not necessity!